# How is aarch64 atomic instructions of Large System Extensions (LSE) implemented in hardware?

Tags: cpu-architecture, atomic, arm64

Is it still based on load-linked/store-conditional (LL/SC)? or need to lock bus/cache as x86 does?

Comment: Instructions like `ldaddal`? https://godbolt.org/z/YrcxWKeq1 .  I assume they take a cache lock like modern x86, so the operation definitely succeeds after gaining exclusive ownership of a cache line.  Making livelock impossible for multiple threads doing `fetch_add` on a single object.  ARMv8 already has LL/SC as separate instructions, it would mostly defeat the purpose to implement the single-instruction atomics as microcode for that.  (I wonder if a really low-end CPU might do that, if it has few cores anyway?)

Comment: See https://www.anandtech.com/show/15578/cloud-clash-amazon-graviton2-arm-against-intel-and-amd/2 for a comparison of classic LL/SC instructions vs. the ARMv8.1 single-instruction atomics on Graviton 2, leading to 4x faster latencies between cores in a benchmark of that.

Comment: BTW, you say "cache lock" like it's a bad thing.  It's *much* better for throughput, just delay MESI responses for that one cache line.  Of course not a bus lock that would stall memory access from all cores and take a long time to go off-core.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for your information.  Is delaying MESI response still based on cache locking? I think it only delays request from non-owner.

Comment: That *is* how a cache lock works: the core that owns the cache line doesn't respond to MESI requests to share or invalidate that line between the load and the store.

Comment: @PeterCordes Single instruction atomics are easier to implement (and provide greater code density) than idiom recognition for a three-instruction LL/[calc]/SC operation, but they can be semantically identical. An implementation which so optimized a variety of such idioms might translate single instruction atomics to the same internal format and that internal format might crack the atomic instruction into a calculation op and a LL/SC that fires twice from the instruction scheduler. Software interfaces constrain reasonable implementations but usually do not define implementations.

Comment: NAK response would be one option. However, if the operation is fast enough — which seems to imply that the operation is not speculative since speculations dependent on in-memory data might take hundreds of cycles to resolve — buffering the request could be an option. I suspect there are a variety of implementation options. E.g., in a weak memory model one could imagine returning the old value with the understanding that the cache block is invalidated after read such that the atomic operation happens after the read — I doubt such complexity could be justified but seems conceptually possible.

Answer (score 1):

Arm64 atomic instructions(LSE) are based on cache-lock(MESI). LSE performs better than LL/SC on multi-core arm64 cpu

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).